# Equations transformations with roots

Tags: logarithms, transformation

How does the following transformation works (do not write that it is easy i want the answer):
$$\ln \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac{\ln \frac{n!}{n^n}}{n}$$

Comment: In general, $~\ln a^b=b\ln a$.

Comment: appreciate your help, i do not know why i did not recognize this

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \ln \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)$$